# encryption using openssl with custom rsa keys

Tags: openssl

I made the following file: `asn_format_mykey.txt`

```bash
asn1=SEQUENCE:rsa_key

[rsa_key]
version=INTEGER:0
modulus=INTEGER:305512047893009
pubExp=INTEGER:78221649299689
privExp=INTEGER:181909
p=INTEGER:17477423
q=INTEGER:17480383
e1=INTEGER:181909
e2=INTEGER:181909
coeff=INTEGER:1611938
```

I run the following commands to get `key.pem` (private key) and `pkey.pem` (public key)

```bash
openssl asn1parse -genconf "asn_format_mykey.txt" -out "key.der"
openssl rsa -inform der -in "key.der" -outform pem > "key.pem"
openssl rsa -inform der -in "key.der" -outform pem -pubout>"pkey.pem"
```

Then, I try to encrypt a small message using `-raw` with `openssl rsautl`

```bash
echo 'aaaa'| openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey "pkey.pem" -raw -out "message.encrypted"
```

and it returns:

```bash
RSA operation error 140063665198744:error:0406B07A:rsa
routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too small for key
size:rsa_none.c:74:
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is a great question. You showed me a new way to generate a custom RSA Private Key (for my own academic purposes).

Comment: your parameters (for the Private Key) look wrong. I guess you know that?  `e1=INTEGER:17477422 e2=INTEGER:17480382
coeff=INTEGER:305512012935204 ` ? It looks like a cut and paste error ( as the Private Expo was correctly set to `181909`)

Answer (score 5):

Your modulus is unusually small and insecure for RSA, but I guess you know that!

The modulus in decimal is `305512047893009` and in hex is `0115DC91160DA11`, which is a number that is exactly 7 bytes long.

You have passed the `-raw` flag, which means you are not using any standard padding scheme, meaning you are responsible for making sure the input message is properly formatted for RSA encryption. In practice, this means your input message must also be exactly 7 bytes long and smaller in value than the modulus, so you will need to create a binary file and use that as the input.

Using a hex editor, I created one with the bytes `01146161616161`, saved that in a file named `message.plain`, then I used the same command as you, but with `-in message.plain` added, and it successfully encrypted the message:

```bsh
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey "pkey.pem" -raw -in "message.plain" -out "message.encrypted"
```

Note: This is all ok as an exercise, but, for any real work, you should not invent your own padding scheme - use one of the existing ones.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Two things, I don't want to encrypt a binary and the other why the message has to be exactly 7 bytes? In rsa the message space are the numbers smaller than the modulus.

Comment: small privexpt (d) relative to n is also insecure, but that belongs on crypto.SX where it has already been answered

Comment: this is an exercise.So my goal is to make it insecure

Comment: If you don't want to encrypt a binary then don't try to encrypt using the "-raw" flag! This is very low level stuff: using "-raw" implies that you will take responsibility for ensuring everything is formatted correctly and this may imply working with binary data. Using PKCS1 padding would avoid this, but you would need a larger modulus for that.

Comment: It has to be 7 bytes because that is the format OpenSSL expects for "no padding" data, i.e. binary data of the same number of bytes as in the modulus. OpenSSL could have been written to automatically pad out the binary data with zeros to the left - but that's not the way it's been implemented. Ultimately, as I said above, if you use "-raw" then you are responsible for ensuring you play by the rules.

Comment: Nice answer. I can you only encrypt with 7 bytes when I use a Null byte at the start. Any idea why?

Comment: The number you encrypt must always be less than the modulus. In the example in this question this means the first byte must be less than `11` (or equal to `11` with the second byte less than `5D`, and so on). The exact number will depend on the specific modulus you are using - so it could be larger or smaller than that. If you're using the exact same modulus as here it shouldn't need to be `00`, as long as its less that `11`.